# Parallel counting words in documents

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Do you have any idea how to make this loop faster?
It counts how frequent each word appears in document.

_documentVectorSpace is a list of objects that contains miscellaneous information about document.

_documentVectorSpace[i].Terms is array of words in document.

_distinctTerms is HashSet of all unique words contained in all documents.

```
Parallel.For(0, _documentVectorSpace.Count, i =>
{
    int count = 0;
    double[] vec = new double[_distinctTerms.Count];
    foreach (string term in _distinctTerms)
    {
        vec[count++] = Weight(_documentVectorSpace[i].Terms, term);
    }
    _documentVectorSpace[i].VectorSpace = vec;
 });
```

where Weight is defined as:

```
private float Weight(string[] document, string term)
{
    return document.Where(s => s == term).Count();
}
```

Comment: for string comparison you should use `String.Equals(s, term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Sounds like "Information Retrieval" assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

You are enumerating your `_documentVectorSpace[i].Terms` for each `term`. You should reverse your loop so you are starting from `_documentVectorSpace[i].Terms` and looking up values in `_distinctTerms`.

Additionally it is hard to tell from this example how efficient your generation of `_documentVectorSpace` is. It is very possible that while it is running quickly it is skipping a lot of work that this function is required to do.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning the document once for each word in `_distinctTerms` is pretty expensive, and you are not fully utilizing the power of HashSet lookups. What you should do is to scan the document once, identify each word that's in `_distinctTerms`, and update the vectors. Something along the lines of: (untested code)

```
Parallel.For(0, _documentVectorSpace.Count, i =>
{
    int count = 0;
    double[] vec = new double[_distinctTerms.Count];
    Parallel.ForEach(_documentVectorSpace[i].Terms, term =>
    {
        if (_distinctTerms.ContainsKey(term))
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref vec[_distinctTerms[term]]);
        }
    });
    _documentVectorSpace[i].VectorSpace = vec;
 });
```

Of course, the `_distinctTerm` should be a dictionary that maps terms to indexes now.